# twisted for python 3.5 on ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, websocket, twisted, django-channels

I tried installing django channels on my virtual environment. But it has failed. And it gives the following error 'failed building wheel for **twisted**'.

What is this about.? And how can i handle this issue?
I have **python 3.5** on my virtualenv, and my OS in **Ubuntu**.

Comment: Can you `pip install twisted` and copy/paste the error you get for us?

Comment: when I use python 2.7 on my virtualenv, that worked. but for python 3.5, it show error

Comment: Failed building wheel for twisted
    Running setup.py clean for twisted
    Failed to build twisted
    Installing collected packages: twisted
    Running setup.py install for twisted ... error

Comment: What you copied is a generic error part, it won't help - copy the _complete_ error stack and update your question with it.

Comment: Do you have the dev packakges? Try `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` then try installing twisted again

Comment: No, it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to install django-channel, do these thee step:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python-pip libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
pip install --verbose twisted
pip install -U Channels
```